# Is there a "New" icon built into jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to flag some menu items in my jQuery mobile site as being "New" by adding a flag or icon.  Is there anything built in?  I don't see any of the standard glyphs or icons that have anything.

Comment: you should be more specific about the icon you're looking for... here is a list of the JQM icons for 1.4.5 http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/icons/

Comment: More specific?  How much more specific than a "New" icon????  An icon that has the letter N followed by the letter e followed by the letter w, in a highlighting background color in such a font or design as to indicate that the item is new to the list.  JQM has every other icon, why would they not have this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a static image and padded the button text to make room.